# iPhone game - full and lite version and game center (bundle id)

Tags: xcode, game-center

I am trying to add game center to an existing game that is already up in the App Store.  The game has both a full and a lite version (with unique bundle ID's for each version).  Since game center depends on the bundle ID, can I get the full and lite versions to play against each other?  My understanding is that each app must have a unique bundle ID since Apple uses it to actually determine the app (for updates and stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Each game have each bundle id, therefore Game Center will be a different score list for each, not public leaderboards and achievements for both full and free app's