# iPad and iPhone version sharing game center

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, gamekit

The text below is copied from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2.

I can't find the setting for the bold text. I'm developing a turned-based game, and I want the iPhone and iPad versions to be able to be able to play against each other.

> In iTunes Connect, you can provide compatibility information that describes which versions of your game can see each other during the matchmaking process. Each compatible group of devices and versions of your game are matched as separate groups. The ability to create these matchmaking groups is quite flexible:
>
> - When you create a new version of a game (such as a bug fix), you can declare whether the new version is compatible with the older versions (and which ones, specifically).
> - **You can create distinct games (with different bundle identifiers) and still allow them to play against each other.**
> - You can create distinct games on both OS X and iOS and match them against each other.

This post, [iPhone game - full and lite version and game center (bundle id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188248/iphone-game-full-and-lite-version-and-game-center-bundle-id), states that it's not possible. I'm confused.